# how to check multiple continue statements in C

Tags: c

In c programming I wish to display 10 numbers using loop, but two numbers 5 and 7 I don't want to display using continue statement here is my code but i am not getting any result errors coming.

```
int j = 10;
for(i=1,i<=j; i++){

if(i==5)(i==7)
{
continue;
printf("%d",i);
}

}
```

Comment: Your `for` loop is wrong. The `if` statement makes no sense, and neither does the place of `continue` inside the braces. What are you "not getting" -- compiler errors? A valid executable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question, use a logical or `||`

```
if(i==5 || i==7)
{
  continue;
}
printf("%d",i);
```

Alternatively, you could use a logical and `&&`

```
if (i!=5 && i!=7)
{
  printf("%d",i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to add one more way of solving the above problem.
my approach is : to loop and print 1-4 and then print 6 and then loop to print 8-10.
something like this.

```
for(int i=1;i<=4;i++)printf("%d",i);
printf("6");
for(int i=8;i<=10;i++)printf("%d",i);
```

hope this helps.But to me the solution by Elliott seems legit and good.